# Hive must specify actual data source(FROM) with UNION ALL

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have a question about Hive `UNION ALL` specification.

This query is a valid Hive query.

```
SELECT
  1 as id,
  'Tom' as name
```

This job returns correct one record result as expected.

```
+----------+----------------+
|    id    |      name      |
+----------+----------------+
|     1    |      Tom       |
+----------+----------------+
```

But when this query is submitted with `UNION ALL`, I'm facing an issue.

```
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM
  members
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 as id,
  'Tom' as name,
```

This SQL produces `Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string` exception. I found all sub-queries of `UNION ALL` must have actual data source with `FROM`. For example, above query can work as expected after rewriting like below.

```
SELECT
  id,
  name
FROM
  members
UNION ALL
SELECT
  1 as id,
 'Tom' as name
FROM (
  SELECT COUNT(1) FROM members
) t
```

Is this a specification of SQL or Hive? Cannot we run the query without `FROM` clause? Or is this a bug of Hive itself?
The version of Hive I'm using is 0.13 with Hadoop 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All `SELECT` statements need `FROM` clause.

Even your first query `SELECT  1 as id, 'Tom' as name` gives error as shown below:[image]

Whereas, if we run `SELECT  1 as id, 'Tom' as name FROM table1` where `table1` is the table in my database, then we have result as below:
[image]

So above two queries prove that `FROM` clause is needed in all `SELECT` statements.

It doesn't matter `UNION ALL` or whatever.

This is the feature of Hive database.

I hope this helps you!!!

Comment: Thanks for comment. But in my environment the query above succeed. Which version did you use? ```hive> SELECT 1 as id, 'tom' as name; OK
1 tom
Time taken: 22.205 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)```

Comment: I am using Hive 1.2.x, which version you are using?

Comment: I'm using 0.13, HDP2.

Comment: I am using Hive 1.2.x, HDP 2.4. But anyway we came to know this issue through your question.